# Docker: cannot set a password for root (ssh access)

Tags: docker, ssh

I run a Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-cli

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server

# add default public key to authorized_keys
#COPY ./ssh/insecure_id_rsa.pub /root/insecure_id_rsa.pub
#RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh \
# && cat /root/insecure_id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys \
# && rm -rf /root/insecure_id_rsa.pub \
#;


RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:passforroot' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

# @see https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Via a docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  deploy:
    build:
      context: ./docker-compose/deploy
    container_name: backend-laravel-deploy
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
      # reserve a tty - otherwise the container shuts down immediately
      # corresponds to the "-i" flag
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - backend-laravel
```

```
$ docker-compose build deploy
$ docker-compose up -d deploy
```

If I uncomment the lines regarding ssh keys, I can login into container via SSH as root (without password, of course) with them.

But, I would use a password, so I tried the other method (based on official guide on docker site) but when I try to connect to `ssh root@localhost -p 2222` it requires for the password that it isn't that wrote on Dockerfile.

How can I change root password for that Dockerfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `docker exec -it <container ID> bash` you can explore the contents of the container, just in case something is wrong.
So far, I could see the following:

```
root@d52693a8ea0c:/etc/ssh# grep "PermitRoot" sshd_config
#PermitRootLogin yes
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
```

It seems the PermitRootLogin flag is commented with `#`. I removed also the hashtag in that file through the Dockerfile sed command that you have:

```
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And after rebuilding and running I could login with the password in the Dockerfile.

Hope this helps!